# How is "OPPOSE" the answer to "Don't act like a pro (6)"?

Tags: cryptic-clues, explanation

Clue from the West Australian Cryptic Crossword 13/5/2021:

> "Don't act like a pro (6)"

Answer: OPPOSE

I can see that "act" gives POSE", but how do you get to "OPPOSE"?

Comment: Apparently this was clue 8-down in the 5 January 2017 [crossword](https://www.pressreader.com/india/hindustan-times-lucknow-live/20170105/281797103672103) of *Hindustan Times (Lucknow)*. Not sure whether the *West Australian* reused that one or whether two setters came up with the same clue independently (which sometimes happens).

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is a [cryptic definition](https://www.crosswordunclued.com/2008/12/cryptic-definitions.html). A "pro" usually means "professional", but here one needs to instead interpret it as "someone on the supporting side" (pro vs contra). If you act unlike someone who supports, you oppose.

Comment: If "like a" can mean to move the "Pro" part infornt, it could be OP